# Trading View - Indicator/Strategy to send buy/sell signals to webhook

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm completely new to TradingView. I was watching a view how to connect TradingView to the exchange. In a video I saw that if you click on the indicator's cog icon, in the Inputs tab, after the actual inputs there is THE ALERTS  section with textareas to input API payload that TradingView is going to include when making a webhook call (to my understanding).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE1bT.png)

However, I don't have those boxes.

Are those text areas are PineScript inputs (if yes, I didn't find what type it could be), or I just need a payed TradingView account to have them?
Thanks.

Looking through documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The ones in your screenshot are generated via the pinescript using the [input.string()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dstring) function.

To use webhooks, you need a paid account on Tradingview. Any paid account will do.

[image]